# CSV File Opening Inline In Browser Rather Than Prompting DL

Tags: php, javascript, csv, export

So I have a php file that creates a csv file with fopen, fputcsv, then fclose and a javascript function for an export button that directs the window to open said csv file. The csv file gets created correctly but when I hit the export button it just opens the csv file in another tab with just the raw data. What I was looking for (and expecting) was it to prompt a download or opening of the file (which I would then open with excel). If I save the page that gets opened now it opens fine in excel but it has the markup from the html (which I don't want) so I'm just trying to see if there is anything in particular that could fix this issue. I have so far tested it in both ie9 and firefox.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Have you sent an appropriate header before sending the output?

```
ob_clean();
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="some_filename_' . date('Ymd') . '.csv"');
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the content type in the header to application/vnd.ms-excel

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

and then send your file back to the browser (this will force it to open excel). If you want to send the proper content type for a CSV set it to text/csv