# Set the way that FF opens a specific file type through HTML / JS

Tags: javascript, php, html, firefox, csv

The interface has the ability to download / open file with .csv format.

Chrome simply download this file, Internet Explorer open it in suitable program (for example, MS Excel) and Firefox tries to open it in a browser and, of course, we see an unreadable text.

Is it possible to specify for FF how to open files of a particular type or something like that?

Comment: What server-side language are you using? You could change the content type and disposition to force the browser to download it, which will do exactly what you want.

Comment: PHP as server-side language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force the file to download instead of opening, which will not change the behavior for Chrome/IE, but in Firefox will stop it from opening in the browser and download it as a file.

[CSV File Opening Inline In Browser Rather Than Prompting DL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11019719/csv-file-opening-inline-in-browser-rather-than-prompting-dl?rq=1)